# Mapkit: Pulsating blue dot and circle

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit

Im trying to get the pulsating blue dot and circle when users zoom in to their current location. But its not appearing quite well. I understand that the codes needed to be places in the viewForAnnotation. Here are the relevant codes. Tell me if you need more! Thanks aloot

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view

//NSLog(@"View for Annotation is called");
MKPinAnnotationView *pin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
pin.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

[pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
pin.canShowCallout = YES;
pin.animatesDrop = YES;

MapEvent* event = (MapEvent*)annotation;
NSLog(@"%@",event.uniqueID);

UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickAnnotation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[rightButton setTitle:event.uniqueID forState:UIControlStateNormal];

pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

return pin;
```

}

Comment: What does "not appearing quite well" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the blue dot with the circle, set the `showsUserLocation` property of the MKMapView to YES.

Comment: Ben is correct. Note, too, that if you're displaying the center of the map based on information from Core Location and have `showsUserLocation` turned on in your MKMapView, you will likely not see the blue dot in the simulator: the simulator always tells MapKit that your current location is Cupertino, CA, USA (Apple's headquarters). It will work fine on the device, however.

Comment: Ohhh! i get it. Thanks dudes for all your help! :D